# how to find button inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have gridview in my project and there is one button inside that gridview.
i want to change that button's property according to gridview cell value

below is my gridview with button

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 style="color:red" id="payDetailH" runat="server" visible="false">Payment Details</h1>
        <br />
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvPayemenDetailNew" CssClass="table table-hover" GridLines="None" runat="server"  
             OnRowCommand="gvPayemenDetailNew_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvPayemenDetailNew_RowDataBound" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnGenNew" runat="server" CommandName="GJobID" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" Text="Ceate Job" CssClass="btn" Enabled="False" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle Height="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
       </div>
</div>
```

and this is my code behind

```
protected void gvPayemenDetailNew_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvPayemenDetailNew.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Button btn = e.Row.FindControl("btnGenNew") as Button;
            if (PayStatus == "Approved")
            {
                btn.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

i got this error

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

[click here to see my screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jhoV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use **[row]** in loop :

```
protected void gvPayemenDetailNew_RowDataBound(object sender, 
GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvPayemenDetailNew.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button btn = row.FindControl("btnGenNew") as Button;
        if (PayStatus == "Approved")
        {
            btn.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop the GridView in the RowDataBound event. It is already executing per row when data is bound to the GridView. And when in a loop you set all the buttons based on the last row value, not per row.

So this should be the correct way, assuming `PayStatus` is a column in the dataset bound to the GridView.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //find the button with findcontrol
        Button btn = e.Row.FindControl("btnGenNew") as Button;

        //use the paystatus of the current row to enable the button
        if (row["PayStatus"].ToString() == "Approved")
        {
            btn.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir but my problem has been solved

Comment: No problem. But try to avoid looping the gridview in the rowdatabound event.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks really good in your code. This the correct way to find controls. Just one suggestion but not sure if its going to work, You can change the way you typecast the button

```
Button btn = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnGenNew");
```