# Posting an image in the gridview:

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]I have a folder full of flags for country of origin.  I want to show it next members in a member list in the grid view.

Here's my code:

```
<asp:Image ID="Flag_image" runat="server" Width="40px" Height="30px" ImageUrl ='<%# Eval(@"../images/Flags/" + countryTESTLabel.Text.Replace(" ", "_") + ".png").ToString() %>'/>
```

Comment: And the problem you face is?

Comment: Is `countryTESTLabel` inside the GridView? If so why not use the value bound to it in the Image also?

Comment: I've tried posting the stack trace but this site refuses to let me.   The countryTestLabel is the country name selected from a dropdown and stored into the database.  I am using that to insert the name of the country into the url to get the right flag image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding image to gridview row dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284961/adding-image-to-gridview-row-dynamically)

Comment: What do you mean Monkey?

Comment: I realized what you meant.  i fixed that ...still isn't working.  But why can't we do it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Still not quite sure what you are trying to do, but your use of Eval looks incorrect. Use

```
<asp:Image ID="Flag_image" runat="server" Width="40px" Height="30px" ImageUrl='<%# @"../images/Flags/" + Eval("ColumnName").ToString().Replace(" ", "_") + ".png" %>'/>
```

If you want to use a Session

```
<asp:Image ID="Flag_image" runat="server" Width="40px" Height="30px" ImageUrl='<%# @"../images/Flags/" + Session["country"] + ".png" %>'/>
```

Comment: I'm not going after a column name.     The first part is the path to the flag images a folder called images.  The label is the country they live in stored in a session in that label,  so I use that to get the name of the flag image then put the ext. on the end.

Comment: Not sure how else I could so it other than the way I am trying.

Comment: Look at the image I attached.

Comment: If you use the Session object, then it is probably empty. Debug your code and see what the value of the Session really is.

Comment: That what I stored int he cuntryTestLabel....why would it become empty?  I am using it to display the same flag on the same page...just in the gridview.  I am thinking itsa the gridview and not me.

Comment: If you look in that image I attached it is working but it isn't sticking the label text in there.

Comment: What happens if you use the RowDataBound event for setting the ImageUrl? See my answer here if you do not know how that works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530488/how-to-find-button-inside-gridview

Comment: I just stored the url in the DB and used that.  I do not think asp image elements are supposed to work in gridviews.